# Move cursor word by word in Alacritty

Tags: macos, terminal, alacritty

I recently started using Alacritty instead of the default Terminal.app on macOS. When using Terminal, I can jump word by word using <kbd>Option</kbd> with left and right arrow keys. In Alacritty this key combination is causing `;3D` and `;2D` to print to the screen instead of the cursor moving.

Is there a way configure Alacritty to jump word by word using <kbd>Option</kbd> and arrow keys?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

With tmux and zsh, add these to the alacritty config:

```yaml
key_bindings:
  ...
  - { key: Right, mods: Alt, chars: "\x1BF" }
  - { key: Left,  mods: Alt, chars: "\x1BB" }
```

Comment: Thank you! Just remember to remove the other Left and Right shortcuts in case you have other configs

Answer (score 8):

Since alacritty [0.13.1](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/releases/tag/v0.13.1), config in yaml format is no longer supported, and the current version of toml doesn't support `\x1B`. Instead, use `\u001B`.

Here is an equivalent example c.f. @cfstras's example. The config file should also be called `config.toml` instead of `config.yml` now.

```
[keyboard]
bindings = [
  { key = "Right", mods = "Alt", chars = "\u001BF" },
  { key = "Left",  mods = "Alt", chars = "\u001BB" },
]
```